# Run time error 3192 Could not find table

Tags: database, vba, ms-access

I am doing a program in Access 2013 and Im trying to make my form insert data into the table (via VBA code), I created a subform (tblClients_subform) containing every "tblClients" data but for some odd reason its throwing me this error:

```
    "Could not find tblClients_subform"
```

Here is my entire block:

```
    "CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO tblClients_subform (ClientID, ClientName, Gender, " & _
    "City, [Address], [Cellphone/Telephone])" & _
    "VALUES (" & Me.txtID & ",'" & Me.txtName & "','" & Me.cboGender & _
    "','" & Me.txtCity & "','" & Me.txtAddress & "','" & Me.txtCellphone & "')"
```

what I am doing wrong? Is there another way to make my form insert data in the subform table?

Comment: You can't insert into a form. Insert into the table instead. If the distinction between a form and a table isn't clear to you, you should find a tutorial and work your way through it.

Comment: But i've seen tutorials of people inserting data into a subform 0.o

Comment: No, you have not, because a **form** is not a **table**. Tables contain data; forms allow people to view or edit that data. As I said, if you don't understand the difference between the two, find a tutorial.

Comment: I did understand the difference between the two of them... My degree is about that... But I was rusty working with Access...I just changed it back to the table (tblClients) and it worked! thanks for the tip!